# MVC5 Partial or Editor Template for Enum and Textbox combination?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, enums, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have the following structure of a few `Enum`s:

```
public Enum Title
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Mr = 1,
    Mrs = 2,
    ...
    Other = -1
}

public Enum Title
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Mr = 1,
    Mrs = 2,
    ...
    Other = -1
}

public enum MaritialStatus
{
    Unspecified = 0,
    Single = 1,
    Married = 2,
    Separated = 3,
    Divorced = 4,
    ...
    Other = -1
}
```

And a number of others. All of these map to an Entity Framework property and related "other" property:

```
public PersonEnums.Title Title { get; set; }
public string TitleOther { get; set; }
public string GetTitle => Title == PersonEnums.Title.Other ? TitleOther : Title.ToString();
```

Now, for the view I'm unsure of the cleanest / easiest way to have these combined into one control / partial / editor template?

I've tried:

Adding a view model:

```
public class EnumWithOtherViewModel
{
    public Enum Enum { get; set; }
    public string OtherValue { get; set; }
}
```

**Partial**

```
@Html.Partial("_EnumWithOther", new EnumWithOtherViewModel { Enum = Model.Title, OtherValue = Model.TitleOther })
```

*_EnumWithOther.cshtml*

```
@model RS3.Models.EnumWithOtherViewModel
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Enum, new { @class = "form-control EnumWithOther" })
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.OtherValue)
```

I get the following error ***Return type 'System.Enum' is not supported.*** on the `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor()` line in the partial

**Display Template**

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => new EnumWithOtherViewModel { Enum = m.Title, OtherValue = m.TitleOther })
```

*EnumWithOther.cshtml*

```
@model EnumWithOtherViewModel
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Enum, new { @class = "form-control EnumWithOther" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Enum, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.OtherValue)
    </div>
</div>
```

I get the following error ***Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.*** when calling the `EditorFor`

I'm a bit lost as to how to best past a generic `Enum` into a template of some sort, along with a `string` other value. What would be the best way to make something reusable for this setup?

The javascript to show and hide the "other" box is trivial, it's just getting everything to map correctly back to EF that I'm stuck with.

Comment: For your second option, using the editor template, have you tried newing up EnumWithOtherViewModel on a previous line and then using that variable in the lambda?

Comment: Good call - just tried it and it does compile but the `EnumDropDownFor` is now just a textbox with the value in, and the ID's are incorrect... So I do not think it's the right route to go down...

Comment: Not sure why you're getting a text box for the enum.  As for the ids being incorrect, if you mean the id attributes in the rendered html - you would be better off having a property of type EnumWithOtherViewModel on your main model, and calling EditorFor on that, rathing the building it on the fly in your view.

Comment: @ngm that makes a lot more sense!! Of course, then it's just a call to the editor for directly from the model. I'll give it a go

Comment: @ngm So if I add `EnumWithOtherViewModel` to my `person` model, EF goes off an creates a lookup table for the Enum / String combo, so again not quite the route I'm looking for... Just checking into making my own HtmlHelper which will take both the Enum and string

Comment: Ah, I see.  Generally I would have a separate PersonViewModel that is mapped from the Person domain entity, and wouldn't use the Person domain entity in the front-end.  Exactly because of situations like this, where sometimes you need something specific to the view that you don't want to tarnish your domain model with.

Comment: And the PersonViewModel would pretty much map directly to the domain model? With a few exceptions such as this? Is there a way to map the two together automatically in the controller and just handle the exceptions?

Comment: Yes it would map quite closely but with exceptions (such as your current one, and others - like domains properties that should never be exposed to the view.)  It's a big topic with lots of opinions, but commonly the view model for a given page/use case is a collection of various parts of various entities from the domain.   For automating the mapping from a given domain entity to its VM countrpart, the AutoMapper (http://automapper.org/) project is commonly used.

Comment: Ah, AutoMapper appears to be just the trick... Life would have been tedious before that!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ngm for putting me on the right path. The cleanest way it seems is with a HTML helper.

```
public static MvcHtmlString EnumWithOther<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, TEnum e, string other)
{
    string r = string.Empty; // Setup the return holder
    string label = e.GetType().Name; // Get the name of the Enum for the ID's
    r += html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => e, new { @id = label, @Name = label, @class = "form-control EnumWithOther" }); // Setup the dropdown for the enum
    r += html.TextBoxFor(m => other, new { @id = $"{label}Other", @Name = $"{label}Other" }); //Setup the textbox for other
    return new MvcHtmlString(r);
}
```

So I can use in my Razor views:

```
@Html.EnumWithOther(Model.Title, Model.TitleOther)
```

The help overrides the default `id` and `name` attributes of the outputted HTML to the correct values for the form to be posted back and mapped correctly on submit.

At this point, you'll still need to handle the JavaScript part to show and hide the "other" textbox as required.